# Integrate Windows Automation (C#) With Cypress Ideal Approach

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, batch-file, automation

I am an Automation Guy and do windows and Web Automation for my company with MSUI(Windows Automation library) and Selenium respectively and all in C# and everything was going fine but then our clients started finding some flicks in selenium and thought to move away from it and came out with an approach of using Cypress ( JS Framework which doesn't use Selenium)

Now, the question to ask is what is the best way to integrate our C# code with out JavaScript framework, as my JavaScript framework is the main executor.

I am open for all the ideas that are feasible .

Some ideas that I already have : 
a) Creating BAT file for invoking Windows Automation and using that Bat file in javascript
b) Creating Node Modules for invoking my automation process and invoking that node module with JavaScript framework.
c) May be creating my Windows Automation TetCases as HTTP Method and exposing them to endpoints and using as a service.

What other options could be used , I am looking for the best and more streamlined process for doing this , out of my options which one do you think is best and may be why?

Comment: While the Automation tag seems appropriate to your question. The Windows Automation in your title, which is based on the Component Object Model, is a specific technology that enables programs like Word and Excel to be programmed. And both JScript and C# can use it.

Comment: With Windows Automation, I mean windows UI Automation